# Cannot enable desktop icon on GNOME 3.20 (Ubuntu 16.04)

Tags: ubuntu-gnome

I used tweak tool, dconf editor to enable desktop icons but desktop does not show anything after restart. Can anyone help me?

Comment: Are you in a Wayland session instead of Xorg by any chance?